# JVectorMap Info box wrong position

Tags: jquery, jvectormap, infobox

Following is the code for setting possition of Info Box on my Jvector map.

```
$(".region-info-box").css({ 'top': mouseY, 'left': mouseX, "display": "block" });
```

Following is the output i get..

[image]

Problem is when i click there on the black round, the info box appears below below the mouse click and slightly right from actual mouse click. Can anyone please suggest me where should i change my code to get info box appeared on the click of the mouse???

Thank you

Comment: This won't completely solve your problem, but do you want to set the `top` property to mouseY? Or do you want the bottom of the info box to be where you click?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Actually i have modified my code to following, and its working properly. it will work for now......    $(".region-info-box").css({ 'top': mouseY - 195, 'left': mouseX - 21.5, "display": "block" });            Thank you. by the way

Comment: $("#info-box").show().css({ position:"absolute", top: event.pageY - $("#info-box").height(), left: event.pageX });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$("#info-box").show().css({ 
    position:"absolute",
    top: event.pageY - $("#info-box").height(),
    left: event.pageX
});

Answer (score 0):

I know you have a something that works currently, but I wasn't sure how well that scaled, so here is another solution that may work for you. It places the bottom left of the div at the point of the mouse click. It takes into account any height of the info-box div.

```
$("#info-box").show().css({ 
    position:"absolute",
    top: event.pageY - $("#info-box").height(),
    left: event.pageX
});
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfritsch/16680k9r/) demonstrating it.

Comment: I think it should work, i'll try it soon. Thank you j.f.